# the bevel on a funnel isnt creating a curved profile AS EXPECTED

Tags: modeling, bevel

I am trying to make a sink, however, when I add a loop cut and try to bevel it to create a curved profile inside, the bevel is adding extra edges along the linear profile instead of bevelling it into a curved one.

[image: the blue is how i want the profile to be]

Answer (score 4):

First create an edge loop, then scale it, and at last bevel it:

[image]

Comment: moonboots you are a lifesaver